# Accessing parent properties when generating a module from a Maven archetype

Tags: maven

I have a number of maven archetypes which I am using to generate a multi-module maven project.

I have a required property on the archetype I use to generate the parent project. This gets added as a property in the pom.xml for the project.

I then generate a module within the project, using a different archetype. I would like the same value to be substituted within some of the resources in that module.

It seems wrong to supply it as a property again when calling the second archetype.

Is it possible to reference parent project properties during the archetype generation process for the module? I want the value to be substituted into files in the src tree of the module, not use a place holder so that it is substituted in the target folder.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

In Maven 3, you can access parent properties by `${project.parent.x}`.

More information can be found in the [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the filtered values to be substituted during the 'generation from archetype' process. So the actual file when the module has been generated contains a real value, not the place holder.