# Maven project version as expression, not constant

Tags: maven

I want to version my parent project differently than the rest of the modules that depend on it, for which I want to have common version.

This is since my parent is defining `dependencyManagement`, `distributionManagement`, `buildManagement`, `*Management`... Parent project really has quite different lifecycle than the rest of the modules. It updates seldomly. It would almost never update if not changing the version for the rest of the modules.

I basically want to do

```
<parent>
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
   <version>5</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
<version>${next-version}</version>
```

and in the parent

```
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
   <version>5</version>
   <properties>
          <next-version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</next-version>
   </properties>
```

While typing this it occurred to me - should this be done by having intermediate parent?

Comment: have you tried instead of `${next-version}` `${parent.next-version}` it is just a thought I do not know if it will work (guess not, but worth a try). And there is no intermediate parent on maven.

Comment: It is possible in fact, see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141290/460557

Comment: I will try it out, but I am really pessimistic about using a property for a project.version

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that Maven itself has multiple levels of inheritance. They are in fact using intermediate parent poms. They have something like this:

`org.apache:apache:16 > org.apache.maven:maven-parent:26 > org.apache.maven:maven:3.3.1-SNAPSHOT > org.apache.maven:maven-core:{inherited.from.parent}`.